Page Life Expectancy Counter is static in SQL Server
I'm looking at Page Life Expectancy on a SQL Server 2019 instance and confused because the results I see don't match my understanding.  Before anyone mentions it, I know there are more relevant metrics to look at.  This is not a question about the relevance of PLE, it is just that I am looking at it, and what I am seeing doesn't match my understanding of what I should be seeing.
I'm using the following code:
SELECT [object_name],
[counter_name],
[cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Manager%'
AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'

And that's steadily climbed over night as I would expect it to.  But for the last 3 hours it's returned the same value - 15343.  My understanding is this metric increases by 1 for every second that a page is expected to stay in memory so I understand if it keeps going up.  I understand if it drops, and I understand if it stays 'about' the same value.  But I don't understand how it can be exactly the same value as previously, particularly over a long period.
Can anyone explain why that counter would be static?
